# window.close showing null after first pass, first pass works fine

Tags: javascript

I'm failing to understand why this works as intended on the first pass but on every subsequent pass itemWindow is null at the itemWindow.close(). Any insight would be appreciated.

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

export const getItems = ids => {
    let itemWindow;
    ids.map(async id => {
        let url = `${some_url}`;
        itemWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');
        await sleep(5000);
        itemWindow.close();
    });
};
```

Comment: There is browser restriction on _blank taget to avoid spam opeining tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That most likely happens because the popup blocker is preventing various windows from opening. Try to disable your popup blocker and don't forget to check if the return value is not `null`.

```js
        let url = `${some_url}`,
        itemWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');
        if (!itemWindow) {
            throw new Error("It wasn't possible to open the window.")
        }
        await sleep(5000);
        itemWindow.close();
```

Comment: Thanks, @D. Pardal, that was it. Chromes built-in popup blocker. Now to figure out why, when I ran this, I now have 50 tabs opening up rather than one opening, waiting for the 5 seconds, and then closing. *sigh* Coding is so much fun!  :)